# How to archive Gmail to PST, so I can access these through Outlook

Tags: gmail, pst, mbox

I know I can link a Gmail to Outlook and move the email into a PST for archiving, but this locks my Outlook for a very long time per mailbox (they are 20-30GB each and I have 2 dozen to do).

I am looking for a way to do the same thing, but in the background.

Right now I have used the takeout from Google, but that generates an MBOX. This I need to convert to EML, then import into Outlook with yet another tool.  So my current approach isn't ideal.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research. Here are a few suggestions on how to properly ask this type of question."

Comment: I'm struggling as a new user. I cannot add comments to other people's questions asking for clarification, then I get told off for asking for these as answers. I ask a genuine question and I get told off because it is about product. I try to delete it and the system says that this will cost me reputation. Not feeling the love, really.

Comment: Use Thunderbird. Way better. I use Linux and I am just getting started with Evolution but T.Bird was great.

Comment: Several thoughts.  First, Outlook gets flaky when the PST file is bigger than about 1 GB (even though recent versions of Outlook spec a much larger max file size).  You're asking for trouble at 20-30 GB.  Find a way to organize and subdivide the contents into a lot more, smaller PST files.  You can open multiple smaller PSTs in Outlook concurrently without the instability.  Second, use a method that doesn't require Outlook in order to convert the files so that Outlook isn't tied up.  BTW, I agree with codeSwift4Life.  I gave up on Outlook & switched to Thunderbird; no more headaches.

Comment: I use Thunderbird myself for Gmail accounts, and it can open the MBOX files natively. The problem is the company was acquired and all the Gmail mailboxes will need to go to Exchange eventually and the archived ones from the former employees need to be readily accessible by Outlook as well. To do with larger files, Outlook 2013 is fairly stable.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Exporting Gmail to local Outlook PST](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31014/354)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use MailStore to do what you want. You can open an MBOX, EML, IMAP profiles and a bunch of other options and import and export among them. Keep in mind the free version is for non-commercial use. I think you will still need to Archive it first to the MailStore database then you can right click the account under Archive and Export it to Outlook.

http://www.mailstore.com/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will give it a try. I am trying to export a couple dozen gmail accounts that are way too big and it's taking me 3 days per account on the long approach of several imports and exports.